# Convert list of phrases into corresponding number

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I’m working on a GPA calculator and I have a list of each grade a student has in their classes. I need to convert the letter grade (A+, B-, etc.) to it’s corresponding numerical value (4.3, 2.7, etc.)
this is what i have so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/mac/Downloads/Data Doc.xlsx')

values = {'A+':'4.3', 'A':'4', 'A-':'3.7', 'B+':'3.3', 'B':'3', 'B-':'2.7', 'C+':'2.3', 'C':'2', 'C-':'1.7', 'D+':'1.3', 'D':'1', 'D-':'.7', 'F':'0'}
l = df.values.tolist()
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to generate numeric grades based on the alpha ones. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'name' : ['John', 'Ellie', 'Bill'], 'grade': ['A', 'A+', 'C-'] } )
values = {'A+':'4.3', 'A':'4', 'A-':'3.7', 'B+':'3.3', 'B':'3', 'B-':'2.7', 'C+':'2.3', 'C':'2', 'C-':'1.7', 'D+':'1.3', 'D':'1', 'D-':'.7', 'F':'0'}
df['numgrade'] = df['grade'].map(values)
```

Output:

```
    name grade numgrade
0   John     A        4
1  Ellie    A+      4.3
2   Bill    C-      1.7
```

If you don't want to keep the alpha values, you can simply use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'name' : ['John', 'Ellie', 'Bill'], 'class 1': ['A', 'A+', 'C-'], 'class 2': ['A', 'B+', 'C+'] } )
values = {'A+':'4.3', 'A':'4', 'A-':'3.7', 'B+':'3.3', 'B':'3', 'B-':'2.7', 'C+':'2.3', 'C':'2', 'C-':'1.7', 'D+':'1.3', 'D':'1', 'D-':'.7', 'F':'0'}
df = df.replace(values)
```

This will replace across the entire dataframe. Output:

```
    name class 1 class 2
0   John       4       4
1  Ellie     4.3     3.3
2   Bill     1.7     2.3
```

Otherwise, you could iterate over the grade columns (using [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select only the ones with `class` at the beginning) e.g.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'name' : ['John', 'Ellie', 'Bill'], 'class 1': ['A', 'A+', 'C-'], 'class 2': ['A', 'B+', 'C+'] } )
values = {'A+':'4.3', 'A':'4', 'A-':'3.7', 'B+':'3.3', 'B':'3', 'B-':'2.7', 'C+':'2.3', 'C':'2', 'C-':'1.7', 'D+':'1.3', 'D':'1', 'D-':'.7', 'F':'0'}
for col in df.filter(regex='^class').columns:
    df[col + ' num'] = df[col].map(values)
```

Output:

```
    name class 1 class 2 class 1 num class 2 num
0   John       A       A           4           4
1  Ellie      A+      B+         4.3         3.3
2   Bill      C-      C+         1.7         2.3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! How would I go about this when I have multiple grades for each student like this: https://imgur.com/a/zIgxfgc

Comment: @user19066051 do you want to keep the alpha grades?

Comment: no they can be replaced if needed

Comment: @user19066051 please see my edit for a couple of alternatives